# Erro MYSQLI com atributo _GET - Fatal error: Call to a member function error() on a non-object in

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Estou com um problema e não sei como resolver.

Estou usando MYSQLI para consultar um banco de dados usando *GET* para pegar o nome da tabela onde a consulta deverá ser feita.

*Código conexão BD:*

```
$hostbd = "localhost";
$usuariobd = "usuario";
$senhabd = "senha";
$bancobd = "bd";

// Conecta ao banco de dados
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostbd, $usuariobd, $senhabd, $bancobd);
// Verifica se ocorreu algum erro
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

*O código é:*

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY `id` DESC');
$modulo = $_GET["modulo"];
$sql->bind_param('s', $modulo);
$sql->execute();
$RESULT = get_result($sql);
$sql->store_result();
$registro = $sql->num_rows;

if ($registro < 1) {
    echo "resultado";
}
```

Quando acesso a pagina o seguinte erro é exibido:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   /caminho/modulo.php on line 24

A linha 22 é essa: **$sql->bind_param('s', $modulo);**

Já dei print na variável `$modulo` e ela está puxando o nome certinho da tabela, se eu colocar o nome da tabela na variável *$modulo* o problema ainda persiste o que me mostra que o problema não é o *GET*.
Caso eu coloque o nome da tabela direto na consulta o erro não é exibido e funciona normalmente.

Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Onde tu está declarando o objeto `$mysqli`?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos $mysqli está declara no código de conexão com o banco de dados. Vou editar o código original para que possa ver

Comment: Você já parou pra pensar que dessa forma algum "espertinho" pode ver os dados de outras tabelas só mudando valores na *quey string*?

Comment: @jbueno Você fala se o esperto mudar o dado enviado via GET? O que me sugere? Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está com erro na sua sintaxe SQL; você não pode utilizar o método `bind_param` para vincular o nome da tabela, por isso o método `prepare` deve estar retornando `false` e não o objeto `statement`, então tente adicionar diretamente o nome da tabela no SQL que deve funcionar.

Comment: Sim, se eu digitar o nome da tabela diretamente na consulta funciona. O problema é que esse código é de alguns módulos, ou seja, precisava pegar o nome da tabela via GET e jogar na consulta.

Comment: Então, mas utilizando o `bind_params` para isso não vai dar certo, assim não ajuda? `$sql = $mysqli->prepare(sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY id DESC', $_GET["modulo"]));` e então remova a linha 22. Apenas faça um tratamento/validação na variável `$_GET["modulo"]` antes, você pode validar se realmente existe.

Comment: Desse jeito que você passou, quando tirei a linha do bind_params o erro passou para a linha de baixo (execute). Porém consegui fazer funcionar seguindo sua lógica: $modulo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["modulo"]);
$consulta = 'SELECT * FROM '. $modulo .' ORDER BY id DESC';
$sql = $mysqli->prepare($consulta)or die($mysqli->error);

Comment: Isso, a ideia é a mesma, você está tratando a variável `$modulo` antes a concatenar ao SQL, assim vai funcionar, apenas com o `bind_param` que não teria possibilidade.